# Getting data attributes from dynamically alterted div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help with something. Im currently making a book-like system that when you scroll down it calls ajax to load the next page when you scroll to the bottom.

the data attributes are stored in:

```
<span hidden id="page" data-vnum="{{ chapters.last.volume.id }}" data-npage="{{ chapters.currentPage + 1 }}" data-ppage="{{ chapters.currentPage - 1 }}" data-cpage="{{ chapters.currentPage }}" data-lpage="{{ chapters.lastPage }}"></span>
```

when the next page is called, it refreshes the span and updates it with new values (the entire span element gets replaced with a new one with the same id but different data values.

the span element gets replaced with the new values, but when I check the call is still retaining the old values. This is the current script:

```
var page = document.getElementById('page');

var book = {
    volumeNumber: page.dataset.vnum,
    nextPage: page.dataset.npage,
    prevPage: page.dataset.ppage,
    currentPage: page.dataset.cpage,
    lastPage: page.dataset.lpage
};

var nextPageUrl = baseSettings.baseURL + '/novel/2/volume/' + book.volumeNumber + '/chapter/' + book.nextPage;

$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        if(book.lastPage > book.currentPage) {
            $(this).request('onNextChapter', {
                data: { pageNumber: book.currentPage },
                url: history.pushState({}, '', nextPageUrl),
                success: function(data) {
                    this.success(data).done(function() {
                        document.getElementById('chapter-header').remove();
                        console.log(nextPageUrl)
                    });             
                },  
            });
        }      
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put this when the next page is loaded

```
$("page").attr({
  "data-vnum": newvalue,
  "data-npage": newvalue,
  "data-ppage": newvalue,
  "data-cpage": newvalue,
  "data-lpage": newvalue
});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that, when the page is loaded its not like a refresh where the values are updated, the ajax changes the values on the span based on the chapter number(page number) which gets pushed in the address bar